# How do I know when a trader is coming to town?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I know that I check whether a trader is coming to town that day if I go to the Trade Depot. But, is there a way to see when a trader is coming in the future, like later in the week?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your calendar.  As part of it's purpose, it also tells you which merchants are going to be coming to town that day.